# Why can't catch exception in async function?

Tags: python-3.x, exception, async-await

I tried to catch exception in my async function, but seems my code doesn't work! [image]

I am using python3.7, and if you need more detail, plz remind me, thanks!!

And here is my code.

```
import asyncio

def bug():
    raise ValueError('something error')

async def logLoop():
    while True:
        try:
            print('here is fine')
            bug()
            await asyncio.sleep(2)


        except:
            # when error happens, it should be run here
            print('catch bug()')
            # handling exception

def listenEvent():

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(
            asyncio.gather(
                logLoop()
            )
        )

    finally:
        loop.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    listenEvent()
```

Comment: Your code works as expected for me on Python 3.10. Are you sure you executed the very same code you posted here?